# calculating square meters in Java

Tags: java

So I am learning Java and want to solve a problem that takes area as an integer input and calculates how many square meters can be made with it.

Example

For example, if you enter an area of 12 meters (input 12), you can make one 3x3 square meters (with a area of 9 meters). That would leave you an area of 3 meters, so you can turn them into three 1x1 square meters.

Comment: Hint: given an integer n, what is the biggest square area inside there? Aka: given 12, how can you find 9?

Comment: Please explain exactly where you are stuck. Edit your question to include your current code.

Comment: Your question is really confusing.  Do you mean "square meters" or "squares whose edges are an integer number of meters"?   I think you are using "square meters" to mean two different things in your problem description.  Also ... please read:  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question about Java, so I will provide you an idea on how to solve it and then you will have to translate the idea into a do-while loop.

What is 12 and 9 in the example? 12 is the available area, 9 is the biggest square lower than the area available. You can calculate the biggest square with the formula `biggestSquare = Math.pow(floor(sqrt(availableArea)),2)` (careful that `^` in Java means XOR).  You produced 1 square and the remainder is simply `remainder = areaAvailable - biggestSquare` **if the biggestSquare is greater than 2**. In that case, if `biggestSquare` is 1, you produced `areaAvailable` squares and the `remainder` is 0. Otherwise you produced `(int) areaAvailable/2` squares and `remainder = areaAvailable%2`. If the remainder is greater than 0, then your new areaAvailable is the old remainder.

A detail on the case biggestSquare > 2: it boils down to 2x^2 > (x+1)^2. A simpler program is to always use the formulas

```
producedSquares += (int) (areaAvailable/biggestSquare)
areaAvailable = areaAvailable % biggestSquare
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @Mussie to the community, using recursive functions, this program gives you the squares you can make based on an input,make sure you handle corner cases(if a =0 or negative), didn't have enough to check those cases

```
 public class CountSquares {

public static int findingSquares(double a) {
    System.out.println((int) floor(sqrt(a)) + "X" + (int) floor(sqrt(a)));
    if ((a - pow(floor(sqrt(a)), 2)) > 0) {
        return findingSquares((a - pow(floor(sqrt(a)), 2)));
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("We can make: ");
    findingSquares(12);
}
```

}

Comment: And since you are learning Java, I wanted to let you know that I have statically imported Math class, you could have a look at static import in java if the concept isn't clear for you.